# Создание и использованием массива внутри цикла

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Если создать простой массив, то все работает нормально:

```
<?php
$data = array();
foreach ($some_array as $page) {
    $data[] = $page;
}

foreach ($data as $page) {
    echo $page;
}

?>
```

Если создать двумерный массив, то начинается проблема вывода - данные массива не выводятся на экран (или я что-то делаю не так или не так понимаю принцип вывода):

```
<?php
$data = array();
foreach ($some_array as $page) {
    $data[] = array(
        name => $page->name,
        url  => $page->url,
    );
}

foreach ($data as $page) {
    //print_r($page);
    echo $page->name;
    echo $page->url;
}

?>
```

PS: Массив принтуется нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, то, что у вас используется такой вариант обращения к данным как `$page->name` намекает на то, что это не массив, а объект типа `stdClass`. Далее, вы неверно пытаетесь создать двумерный массив и потом обратиться к его свойствам (видимо, решили обращаться по аналогии с тем, как обращаетесь к свойствам `stdClass`, но это неверно). Верный будет такой код:

```
<?php
$data = array();
foreach ($some_array as $page) {
    $data[] = array(
        `name` => $page->name,
        `url`  => $page->url,
    );
}

foreach ($data as $page) {
    //print_r($page);
    echo $page['name'];
    echo $page['url'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Ключевой момент был в выводе $page['name'] - спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @L3n1n верно. Без проблем, пишите еще ;)